# Securing a simple Linux server that holds a MySQL database?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security

A beginner question, but I've looked through many questions on this site and haven't found a simple, straightforward answer:

I'm setting up a Linux server running Ubuntu to store a MySQL database.

It's important this server is secure as possible, as far as I'm aware my main concerns should be incoming DoS/DDoS attacks and unauthorized access to the server itself.

The database server only receives incoming data from one specific IP (101.432.XX.XX), on port 3000. I only want this server to be able to receive incoming requests from this IP, as well as prevent the server from making any outgoing requests.

I'd like to know:

1. What is the best way to prevent my database server from making outgoing requests and receiving incoming requests solely from 101.432.XX.XX? Would closing all ports ex. 3000 be helpful in achieving this?
2. Are there any other additions to the linux environment that can boost security?

I've taken very basic steps to secure my phpmyadmin portal (linked to the MySQL database), such as restricting access to solely my personal IP address.

To access the database server requires the SSH key (which itself is password protected).

Comment: Just do not give the db server any public IP and you should be fine in most cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To limit connections to your 101.432.x.x IP, you would start with `iptables`. A basic firewall setup for port 3306 (the default mysql port) could look something like this:

```
# allow any localhost interface traffic
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
# allow any related traffic to existing connections
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state related,established -j ACCEPT
# only allow certain host to mysql
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3306 -s 101.232.155.155 -j ACCEPT
# drop all traffic by default
iptables -P INPUT DROP
# oh, add your ssh source address to allow remote connections
iptables -I INPUT 3 -p tcp --dport 22 -s 203.203.203.203 -j ACCEPT
```

If you are concerned about limiting outbound (egress) traffic, then you would use a rule on the OUTPUT chain; it gets tricky however. Egress filtering involves a rule for every service which your server needs to use to communicate with the outside world. `DNS`, `NTP`, `HTTP/HTTPS` (for updates), `SMTP` for admin email, syslog traffic, etc,etc.  The beauty of egress filtering is once you've established "normal" egress traffic, alerting on the anomalies becomes an easy win. A simple example to get started:

```
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -F OUTPUT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state related,established -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 123 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d 111.222.33.44 --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
```

You may want to disable the `80,443` until you actually perform updates on the server. Otherwise, malicious software will just egress over one of those ports and you wouldn't know. Using 'allowed' destination IP addresses for egress is really the best way to do it (as in the `--dport 25` line above).

In general, server hardening is a much more involved process. You are off to a good start thinking about how to limit connections to only what's needed.

Consider the following also:

- remove all extra software not needed for operation of the server
- limit running services (`netstat -topnavelu` to investigate)
- stay updated with all current patches
- monitor for anomalies (`iptables -A INPUT -j LOG` , fail2ban,etc)
- drop `ipv6` if not needed (`ipv6.disable=1` in kernel boot arg)
- use `PubKeyAuthentication yes` and `PasswordAuthentication no` in sshd_config
- limit logins via `pam` in `/etc/security/access.conf`
- encrypt all net traffic in one way or another**
- store system logs on remote syslog server**
- regularly scan system for malware/bad permissions/SUID files, etc (such as in /var/www)

There are many good guides out there, but it can be overwhelming for someone new to it all. These two seem to cover the bases well:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-securing-your-linux-vps

https://www.rootusers.com/23-hardening-tips-to-secure-your-linux-server/

** note: consider running your mysql traffic over [Stunnel](https://www.knthost.com/networking/using-stunnel-secure-mysql-database).

Comment: +1 to the above answer

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are behind a NAT, in your Mysql config you can change your bind-address.

```
#Replace X's with actual IP address
bind-address=<internal-ip>
port=3000
```

This will bind MySql to only listen on that single address and port

Then I would add a destination NAT rule to translate between 101.432.XX.XX:3000 to internal-ip.

Finally add a source policy in your firewall to Drop all packets coming from internal-ip. I have a similar setup with a server I over see.

Here are few links to other resources for hardening Ubuntu servers

http://bodhizazen.net/Tutorials/SSH_security - Hardening SSH
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-mysql-and-mariadb-databases-in-a-linux-vps - MySQL Hardening
Hope these help